# Expanding/Collapesing UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am trying trying to do accordion table with tapped in header of tableview
my sample code is below..

```
    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 UIView *headerView              = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
headerView.tag                  = section;
headerView.backgroundColor      = [UIColor whiteColor];
  UILabel *headerString           = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-20-50-20, 50)];

     headerString.textColor          = [UIColor blackColor];
      BOOL manyCells                  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue];
    if (!manyCells) {
        headerString.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    }
    else
    {
       headerString.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    }
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 40, 40)];
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imgarray[section]];

    headerString.text=sectionTitleArray[section]; 
    headerString.textAlignment      = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    headerString.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    [headerView addSubview:headerString];
    [headerView addSubview:imgView];
    UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
    [headerView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];


    UIImageView *upDownArrow        = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"downArrowBlack"]];



    upDownArrow.autoresizingMask    = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    upDownArrow.frame               = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-40, 10, 20, 20);
    [headerView addSubview:upDownArrow];

    if([headerString.text isEqualToString:@"Contact Us"])
    {
        upDownArrow.hidden=YES;

    }

    //return headerView;
}

    return headerView;
  }
```

and my sectionHeaderTapped :

```
    - (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    BOOL collapsed  = [arrayForBool[indexPath.section] boolValue];
    collapsed       = !collapsed;
    arrayForBool[indexPath.section] = @(collapsed);

    //reload specific section animated
    NSRange range   = NSMakeRange(indexPath.section, 1);
    NSIndexSet *sectionToReload = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
    [self.tableView1 reloadSections:sectionToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

}
```

if  open one header means i want to collapse other header in that tableview.how to do this?
help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to maintain this in - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: for every rows i want to do this tap action ?

Comment: yes you can do this in this method or you can use tableview beginupdates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved the same goal in a slightly different way. Let me explain step by step.

1) I have created a `UIView` subclass `MYCollapsableTableHeaderView` with a `MYCollapsableTableHeaderViewDelegate` declaration exactly like this.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MYCollapsableTableHeaderView;

@protocol MYCollapsableTableHeaderViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void)collapsableTableHeaderViewTapped:(MYCollapsableTableHeaderView *)collapsableTableHeaderView;

@end

@interface MYCollapsableTableHeaderView : UIView

@property (assign, nonatomic) id <MYCollapsableTableHeaderViewDelegate> collapsableTableHeaderViewDelegate;

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger section;
@property (nonatomic, getter = isExpanded) BOOL expanded;

+ (instancetype)collapsableTableHeaderViewWithCollapsableTableHeaderViewDelegate:(id <MYCollapsableTableHeaderViewDelegate>)delegate;

- (CGFloat)collapsableTableHeaderViewHeight;

- (void)giveText:(NSString *)text;

@end
```

2) Populate the necessary amount of `MYCollapsableTableHeaderView` object and keep the reference with the help of `NSMutableArray` in your `UITabelVewController` subclass.

```
MYCollapsableTableHeaderView *collapsableTableHeaderView = [MYCollapsableTableHeaderView collapsableTableHeaderViewWithCollapsableTableHeaderViewDelegate:self];

[headerViews addObject:collapsableTableHeaderView];
```

3) As you done I used the `UITableView` delegate method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    MYCollapsableTableHeaderView *collapsableTableHeaderView = headerViews[section];

    [collapsableTableHeaderView setSection:section];
    [collapsableTableHeaderView giveText:[self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section]];

    return collapsableTableHeaderView;
}
```

integrate the `MYCollapsableTableHeaderView` objects.

4) Under the method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

I check the isExpanded property like this

```
if ([headerViews[section] isExpanded]) return [currentSection.items count];
else return 0;
```

where headerViews is the `NSMutableArray` which keeps all the `MYCollapsableTableHeaderView` objects.

5) With the `MYCollapsableTableHeaderViewDelegate` implementation

```
- (void)collapsableTableHeaderViewTapped:(MYCollapsableTableHeaderView *)collapsableTableHeaderView {

    NSUInteger section = [collapsableTableHeaderView section];
    BOOL isExpanded = [collapsableTableHeaderView isExpanded];

    for (MYCollapsableTableHeaderView headerView* in headerViews) {

         [headerView setExpanded:NO] // here you are collapsing all headerviews.
    }

    [headerViews[section] setExpanded:YES]; // adding and exception for the selected one

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:isExpanded? UITableViewRowAnimationBottom:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
}
```

thats it.

NB: I prefer to use the `UIView's`

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [self setExpanded:!_expanded];

    if ([self.collapsableTableHeaderViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(collapsableTableHeaderViewTapped:)]) [self.collapsableTableHeaderViewDelegate collapsableTableHeaderViewTapped:self];
}
```

method to detect the touch rather adding an `UITapGestureRecognizer` object.

Hope it will help you.